# PHPExcel: how to set date format for a cell

Tags: php, date, formatting, phpexcel

I need to save a date to Excel file, it must be output in format "dd/mm/yyyy" (or the local date format of the user), and to be treated as a date so a column of them could be sorted correctly.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once("../PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_gzip;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);

//I didn't find dd/mm/yyyy format, so I used yyyy-mm-dd
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "2014-10-16");
$sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow(0, 1)
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2
);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

It creates a file, but instead of my local date format I see: "2014-10-16" and the format of the cell is "All formats" -> "yyyy-mm-dd". I wanted it to be parsed and output in my local date format.

I looked into the source code of `PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php`, and found many date formats:

```
const FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2 = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
const FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD = 'yy-mm-dd';
const FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY = 'dd/mm/yy';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYSLASH = 'd/m/y';
const FORMAT_DATE_DMYMINUS = 'd-m-y';
...
```

But I am not sure what to use. How can I achieve the desired goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "2014-10-16");
```

Sets a **string** value in the cell, not a date. Just because you interpret that as a date, doesn't mean that computer programs automagically interpret it as a date.

Look at the date Examples  in the PHPExcel [Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell) and [Examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types.php#L94), and you'll see that you need to set the cell value to a MS Excel serialized timestamp (a float value of the number of days since 1st January 1900). You can use the PHPExcel functions like `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` to convert human dates/PHP DateTime objects/Unix timestamps to MS Excel Serialized timestamps.

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( '2014-10-16' ));
```

Once you've stored the value as a timestamp, you can then apply whatever date format mask you want to that cell to get your desired formatting

Comment: In xdebug PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( )) shows always number, do not get it. Is it somehow encoded as number? I see in my spreadsheet some cells have format date, and they show the date, but some have  format not date and shows this funciton outpuyt number. Why is that?

Comment: This doesnt work for me. This returns "false" value. But it leads to goal anyway. Ive added
"$date = new DateTime('2014-10-16');"
as mentioned in another answer here - and used $date instead of your string in your example and than it works perfect!

Answer (score 8):

This code generates 4 cells in date format.

```
<?php
include_once("../PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_gzip;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);

$format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; ++$i)
{
    $date = new DateTime('2016-12-0'.$i);
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $i, 
                                       PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $date ));

    $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow(0, $i)
        ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode($format);
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

Comment: You don't need to convert a DateTime object to a Unix timestamp before calling `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()`.... you can pass the DateTime object to `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` instead of the timestamp

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated the answer. When I tried to pass a string '2016-12-01' to `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel`, like you shown, it didn't work.

Comment: Then you've discovered a major bug in PHPExcel that only you have ever encountered before. The `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` will accept a unix timestamp, a DateTime object, or a string in  format that PHP's built-in `strtotime()` function will recognise, and `'2016-12-01'` is a perfectly valid string.... I've just tested it with that value myself, and it worked exactly as expected

Comment: @MarkBaker Maybe, I have an outdated version: my library is from year 2012?

Comment: `1.8.1` is the latest production version, from 30th April 2015; although the develop branch is pretty stable as well

Comment: This works after following line:
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "2014-10-16");

3rd param should be date in string.