# How to format a custom date that excel can group on data sort PHPexcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to format a excel column using PHPexcel as a custom date so that when user open it on MS excel 2007 the date on data sort is properly group see image.

[image]

I inspected the cell format and the format is below.

[image]

My PHP code is below.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('S:S')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('m/d/yyyy h:mm');
```

But my output is below, Any advice how to achieve above format.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts i updated my question to add the cell format i tried what you suggested by still the same output, my code output cell format is the same from what i want to achieve.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933312/phpexcel-how-to-set-date-format-for-a-cell).

Comment: @JaydeepMor putting the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel` worked for me thanks!